# MATLAB out of memory on linux despite regular "clear all"

Tags: matlab, memory

I am batch processing a bunch of files (~200) on MATLAB, in essence

```
for i = 1:n, process(i); end
```

where `process(i)` opens a file, reads it and writes out the output to another file.  (I am not posting details about `process` here because it is hundreds of lines long and I readily admit I don't fully understand the code, having obtained it from someone else).

This runs out of memory after every dozen of files or so.  Of course, on Linux, the `memory` function is not available so we have to figure it out "by hand".  Well, I thought there is some memory leak, so let's issue a `clear all` after every run, i.e.

```
for i = 1:n, process(i); clear all; end
```

No luck, this still runs out of memory.  At the point where this happens, `who` says there's just two small arrays in memory (<100 elements).  Note that quitting MATLAB and restarting solves the problem, so the computer certainly has enough memory to process a single item.

Any ideas to help me detect where the error comes from would be welcome.

Comment: When you say 'there's just two small arrays in memory', do you mean in the workspace of the caller script, or in the workspace of 'process'? It seems to me what is happening is that you might be reading a massive file that 'process' needs to keep in memory, and you're hitting a limit for your machine. Instead of running the for loop, you should identify which file is creating the problem and see if you can run 'process' on that file alone.

Comment: This is in the workspace of the caller script.  You are *correct* that `process` could have a larger workspace, but it is certainly possible to process every single file individually (e.g. by restarting MATLAB between each call), so that's not the issue.

Comment: Persistent variables or similar stuff can cause such problems. Not sure how to isolate the problem.

Comment: you can try `clear classes`, which is more widespread than just `clear all`, but even that will not clear all objects like  [`persistent variables`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#bt2itb8).

Comment: does it get stuck in the same file every time?

Comment: you can also try using 'pack' after your clear all call. you could do for example if rem(10,ii)==0; pack; end so that you don't have to pack memory every step of your loop.

Comment: another possibility: that your 'process' code is not closing the files being processed. You could try a 'fclose('all')' at the end of your for loop to be sure.

Comment: Is there a line with the command `mlock` in `process` ?

Comment: The loop does not always fail at the same point.  There is no `mlock` in the sources, and running `clear classes` and `pack` at every iteration doesn't help either.

Comment: What version is this? Older versions (at least on windows) had lots of memory leaks. 2011b seems ok.

Comment: 2015a, so no luck there either.

Comment: try `dbstop if error` and inspect the workspace the next time it errors. Follow the code up from there if it's not directly obvious...

Comment: You must've seen these pages already, but in case you didn't: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html ; http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html#brh72ex-56 . As a replacement for `memory` you can try this: https://scivision.co/matlab-free-memory-on-linuxmac/

Comment: Is there a MEX Function being called that is allocating memory or doing something leaky?

Comment: There's no MEX function involved.  I'll try stepping thru the debugger once I manage to reproduce the bug, clearly it is dependent on how fragmented the memory is (there's no memory issue when running on a freshly rebooted computer).

Comment: could be Java-related. You can try to force Java garbage collection periodically in your loop. E.g., `jrt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime; jrt.gc;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probable not the solution you are hoping for but as a workaround you could have a shell script that loops over several calls to Matlab.